# Sorting an array of linked list nodes

Tags: c, qsort

I am writing a task scheduler in C. I managed to copy the nodes of linked list that contains the tasks to an array. I am. trying to implement the shortest job first scheduling algorithm and here is the code:

```
void schedule (struct Node* head){
    struct  Node* temp = head;
    struct Node** ordered_list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*) * count);
        
    for (int i =0 ; i <count-1; i++) {
        ordered_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        ordered_list[i] = temp;
        temp = temp-> next;
    }
    
    
    ordered_list[count-1] = temp;

    

    qsort(ordered_list, count, sizeof(struct Node ), cmpfunc);
```

the compare function is

```
    int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void* b){
        struct Node *node1 = (struct Node*) a;
        struct Node *node2 = (struct Node*) b;
        return (node1->task->burst - node2->task->burst);
    
    }
```

I am stuck with segmentation faults. I found that it is in the qsort function. Yet, I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Your second for-loop instantly leaks memory in the first two lines. Start by thinking about that. Your comparator is wrong regardless. qsort passes as each argument the *address* of each element being sorted. You're sorting a sequence of *pointers*, which means the addresses passed to the comparators are addresses of pointers, e.g. *pointer to pointer*. Therefore your comparator is missing a level of indirection.

Comment: @WhozCraig so what do you think I should do to get over this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're using to sort your linked list is to utilize an intermediate pointer-bed. i.e. a sequence holding all the node pointers, then using a  canned sorting operation like `qsort`, then rebuilding the list.

The most fundamental problem is your comparator. It's wrong. The `qsort` comparator should expect the *address* of each element being sorted as arguments. Since you're sorting a sequence of pointers, the address of an element is therefore the address of a pointer. E.g. a *pointer to pointer*.

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void* b)
{
    const struct Node * const * pp1 = a;
    const struct Node * const * pp2 = b;

    return ((*pp1)->task->burst - (*pp2)->task->burst);
}
```

In addition to that, but not related to your sorting issue, your build loop for your pointer bed leaks memory. This line:

```
ordered_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

is pointless. get rid of it.

---

**Working Example**

The following is a trivial working example you can adapt as needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int cmpfunc(const void *arg1, const void *arg2)
{
    const struct Node * const * lhs = arg1;
    const struct Node * const * rhs = arg2;
    return (*lhs)->data < (*rhs)->data ? -1 : (*rhs)->data < (*lhs)->data;
}

struct Node *schedule(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node **arr = NULL;
    size_t capacity = 0;
    size_t size = 0;

    while (head)
    {
        if (size == capacity)
        {
            size_t new_capacity = capacity ? 2 * capacity : 1;
            void *tmp = realloc(arr, new_capacity * sizeof *arr);
            if (!tmp)
            {
                perror("Failed to expand sorting array");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            arr = tmp;
            capacity = new_capacity;
        }

        arr[size++] = head;
        head = head->next;
    }

    if (size > 0)
    {
        qsort(arr, size, sizeof *arr,  cmpfunc);
        struct Node **pp = &head;
        for (size_t  i=0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            *pp = arr[i];
            pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }
        *pp =  NULL;

        // don't need this anymore
        free(arr);
    }

    return head;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    // build a random linked list
    struct Node *head = NULL, **pp = &head;
    for (int i=0; i<20; ++i)
    {
        *pp = malloc( sizeof **pp );
        (*pp)->data = 1 + rand() % 99;
        printf("%d ", (*pp)->data);
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    *pp = NULL;
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    head = schedule(head);
    for (const struct Node *p = head; p;p = p->next)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    // free the list
    while (head)
    {
        void *p = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(p);
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output** (varies)

```
54 85 69 83 13 69 74 64 90 19 83 80 92 25 95 93 49 38 6 83 
6 13 19 25 38 49 54 64 69 69 74 80 83 83 83 85 90 92 93 95
```

Comment: nicer, more complete!

Comment: @ahmedbotta In your case I'd also focus on how/whether each node `task` member is what you think it is. Read, and understand, the working example I included, then apply it to your code, and *get a debugger*; you're going to need it.

Comment: Ye I tried what you said and it worked. Do you recommend any other algorithm I should do?

Comment: @ahmedbotta: Alternatives to quick sort are for example [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). They have the advantage that they have better worst-case [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) (`O(n) log(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`).

Answer (score 1):

In the loop in `schedule`, you allocate space & assign it to `ordered_list[i]`, then immediately overwrite that assignment.  And since you never assign anything to the `next` of anything, following that link will be problematic.

Comment: but when I tried to print the ordered_list, I found that nodes were successfully allocated in the array.  I only got a problem with the sorting part

Comment: @ahmedbotta listen to Scott : You are leaking everything you allocate in the for-loop. Also: what is `temp`? Are you running the same code you have shown here?

Comment: @ahmedbotta Then you were (un)lucky. Common thing when you invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: It seems like i need to read more about memory leakage. Thanks lads